# How to edit the dot above an " i " in a certain font?

Tags: fonts, edit, webfonts

I want to change the color of the dot in the letter "i" to be orange, while the remaining part of the "i" to stay white.

For instance, I've found  a free front called Quicksand on this website:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/quicksand?q%5Bterm%5D=quicksand&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y

How do I edit the color of just the dot in the "i" ?
Is it legal to edit fonts like this?

Thanks everyone

Comment: In this day and age?? We landed on the moon but I can't change the color of the dot? Sort of joking, but it just seems like such a simple thing.

Comment: Barely.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType#Color

Answer (score 0):

This is only a bare outline: as SLaks pointed out, fonts are mostly monochrome by design. However, there is a character [small letter dotless i](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131/index.htm) and [combining dot above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm).

So, you can fake it, but it doesn't look very convincing, and it's not automatic for all your i's:

```html
<div style="font-size:40px">&#x0131;<span style="color:orange">&#x0307;</span></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I really appreciate the feedback both of you. I'll just stick to using an image for my header instead.  Thanks!